# class or struct for extracting maths (Swift)

Tags: swift, class, structure

hi all i'm very new to programming and it's turning into a bit of a mission.

I'm trying to create a class with function to do some basic maths. However I'm still learning how to extract the new value and maybe either pass in on within my class/func or pass into another.

here is what I have so far

```
class fuel {
var rate = 3.7
var laps: Double = 13.0
var totalFuel: Double

init (rate: Double, laps: Double, totalFuel: Double){
    self.rate = rate
    self.laps = laps
    self.totalFuel = totalFuel

    }
func fuelMaths (fuel: Double) -> Double {
    self.totalFuel = (rate * Double(laps))
    print(self.totalFuel)

    }
```

} 
fuelMaths(self.totalFuel)

I'm getting an unresolved identifier error  when I call "fuelMaths" or am I meaning to of created a struct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding class vs. struct, this seems like a struct is a better choice because it only contains a few stored properties which are all value types.

Even so, here are the issues:

1) Your `fuelMaths` instance method is not returning a value. Your implementation should resemble this:

```
func fuelMaths(fuel:Double) -> Double {
    // "someValue" contains your result
    return someValue
}
```

2) The reason you are getting an unresolved identifier error is because you need to first declare an instance of `fuel`, and then call `fuelMaths` on that instance:

```
// someRate, someLaps, someTotal, and someFuelValue previously defined

let myFuel = fuel(rate: someRate, laps: someLaps, totalFuel: someTotal)
let myReturnedValue = myFuel.fuelMaths(someFuelValue)
```

Finally, it appears that `totalFuel` is a good candidate for a computed property instead of a stored property. This eliminates your need for the `fuelMaths` method. Just perform the calculations that are in `fuelMaths` inside the body of your computed property instead. It also means that your initializer only needs to provide two arguments for `rate` and `laps`:

```
var totalFuel: Double {
    return rate * laps
}

init(rate:Double, laps:Double) { //... }
```

One more thing, the convention is to capitalize the names of your classes and structs.

EDIT:

The class version of your code might look like this:

```
class Fuel {
    var rate = 3.7  // default value tells compiler this is a Double
    var laps = 13.0
    var totalFuel: Double {
        return rate * laps
    }

    init(rate:Double, laps:Double) {
        self.rate = rate
        self.laps = laps
    }
}
```

The struct version of your code might look like this (notice that it doesn't require you to explicitly define an initializer, unlike a class):

```
struct Fuel {
    var rate = 3.7
    var laps = 13.0
    var totalFuel: Double {
        return rate * laps
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the response, I'm sure your solution works however I'm having a mental blank on how I'd structure your new code into my existing code.

Comment: Updated response with integrated solution

Comment: brilliant stuff thanks for the help, I've studied your reply and have now successfully applied it to my project.